# A user does something but stays at the same page

Tags: javascript

A user is clicking the button with id continueButton. If they stay on the same page upon after clicking the button, then I trigger UK-AwesomeEvent.

**My effort so far**

```
Bootstrapper.on('click', '#continueButton', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //if nothing happens then trigger this event
    if (document.title === 'Current address' && doNotGetRedirectedToAnotherPageWhenButtonIsClicked) {
      Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger("UK-AwesomeEvent");
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

**Desired outcome**

In place of `doNotGetRedirectedToAnotherPageWhenButtonIsClicked` I want a method that basically states that a user is not redirected to another page. I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: What's the exact problem? If your button triggers a page change, the JS will get unloaded

Comment: My question is: What about the case where the button does not trigger a page change?

Comment: Can you share the code that leads to this situation? Please provide a full working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can call the `preventDefault()` method of the event object…

```
Bootstrapper.on('click', '#continueButton', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
```

to prevent whatever the default behaviour is (and in this context it sounds like that behaviour is "A submit button is triggering the submission of a form").

**However**, because you have used `setTimeout`, it is **too late**. The event handler function has already finished and the form submission started.

The closest you could come would be to **always** prevent the default behaviour and then restart the form submission if you later change your mind:

```
Bootstrapper.on('click', '#continueButton', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.title === 'Current address') {
      Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger("UK-AwesomeEvent");
    } else {
        event.target.form.submit();
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

(Note there is a fair chunk of educated speculation here because you didn't provide a complete, reduced test case)